# Cmake - freetype, sdl, sdl-image

Tags: cmake, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I have the following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(ExternalProject)

project(freetype_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
set(LIBS_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs)

set(FREETYPE_VER "2.5.3")
set(SDL2_VER "2.0.3")

# ---

# Freetype library
ExternalProject_Add(freetype_project
    URL http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-${FREETYPE_VER}.tar.gz
    PREFIX ${LIBS_DIR}/freetype
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(freetype_project SOURCE_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(freetype_project BINARY_DIR)

set(FREETYPE_SRC ${SOURCE_DIR})
set(FREETYPE_BIN ${BINARY_DIR})

# ---

# SDL library
ExternalProject_Add(sdl2_project
    URL http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-${SDL2_VER}.tar.gz
    PREFIX ${LIBS_DIR}/SDL2
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(sdl2_project SOURCE_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(sdl2_project BINARY_DIR)

set(SDL2_SRC ${SOURCE_DIR})
set(SDL2_BIN ${BINARY_DIR})

# ---

# SDL_image library
ExternalProject_Add(sdl2_image_project
    URL https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.0.tar.gz
    DEPENDS sdl2_project
    PREFIX ${LIBS_DIR}/SDL2_image
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND LDFLAGS=-L${SDL2_BIN} CFLAGS=-I${SDL2_SRC}/include SDL2_CONFIG=${SDL2_BIN}/sdl2-config <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --enable-shared=no
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(sdl2_image_project SOURCE_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(sdl2_image_project BINARY_DIR)

set(SDL2_IMAGE_SRC ${SOURCE_DIR})
set(SDL2_IMAGE_BIN ${BINARY_DIR})

# ---

include_directories(${FREETYPE_SRC}/include)
include_directories(${SDL2_SRC}/include)
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_SRC}/include)

set(SOURCE freetype_test.cpp)

add_executable(ft_test ${SOURCE})
add_dependencies(ft_test
    freetype_project
    sdl2_project
    sdl2_image_project
)

target_link_libraries(ft_test
    ${FREETYPE_BIN}/libfreetype.a
    ${SDL2_BIN}/libSDL2.a
)
```

I ran it like: `cmake .` and then `make`.

The first time I get the following error:

```
checking for SDL... checking for sdl2-config... /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/sdl2-config
checking for SDL - version >= 2.0.0... /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project/configure: line 12359: /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/sdl2-config: Permission denied
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project/configure: line 12360: /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/sdl2-config: Permission denied
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project/configure: line 12363: /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/sdl2-config: Permission denied
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project/configure: line 12365: /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/sdl2-config: Permission denied
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project/configure: line 12367: /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/sdl2-config: Permission denied
no
*** Could not run SDL test program, checking why...
*** The test program compiled, but did not run. This usually means
*** that the run-time linker is not finding SDL or finding the wrong
*** version of SDL. If it is not finding SDL, you'll need to set your
*** LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or edit /etc/ld.so.conf to point
*** to the installed location  Also, make sure you have run ldconfig if that
*** is required on your system
***
*** If you have an old version installed, it is best to remove it, although
*** you may also be able to get things to work by modifying LD_LIBRARY_PATH
configure: error: *** SDL version 2.0.0 not found!
CMakeFiles/sdl2_image_project.dir/build.make:109: recipe for target 'libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project-stamp/sdl2_image_project-configure' failed
make[2]: *** [libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project-stamp/sdl2_image_project-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:180: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sdl2_image_project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl2_image_project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I do the following: `chmod -R 777 /home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2` and then `make` again, but then I get the following error:

```
r: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libSDL2_image.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libSDL2_image.la" && ln -s "../libSDL2_image.la" "libSDL2_image.la" )
libtool: link: gcc -I/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/include -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/include -D_REENTRANT -o showimage showimage.o -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -pthread  -L/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build ./.libs/libSDL2_image.a -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -pthread
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/libSDL2.a(SDL_dynapi.c.o): In function `get_sdlapi_entry':
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c:227: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c:228: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c:227: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/src/dynapi/SDL_dynapi.c:228: undefined reference to `dlsym'
...
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project-build/libSDL2.a(SDL_systhread.c.o): In function `SDL_SYS_CreateThread':
/home/xubuntu/git/testCmake/libs/SDL2/src/sdl2_project/src/thread/pthread/SDL_systhread.c:91: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:516: recipe for target 'showimage' failed
make[3]: *** [showimage] Error 1
CMakeFiles/sdl2_image_project.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target 'libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project-stamp/sdl2_image_project-build' failed
make[2]: *** [libs/SDL2_image/src/sdl2_image_project-stamp/sdl2_image_project-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:180: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sdl2_image_project.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sdl2_image_project.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've tried for hours, but I just can't install sdl, sdl-image using cmake.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already put '-dl' ? if so, try -Wl,--no-as-needed before -ldl

Comment: Does it go to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or to the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` on `ExternalProject_Add`?

Comment: I think the CMAKE_CFLAGS will be okey...you need to add linker flag exactly..so the next option you have to set in your CMakefile.txt CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS,
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS,
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS or
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS.

Comment: I think CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS don't follow to the `ExternalProject_Add(sdl2_image_project...`.

Comment: `I think CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS don't follow to the ExternalProject_Add` - Yes, CMake variables from the main project are not automatically propagated to subprojects. You set `CFLAGS` for `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`, this variable is actually passed to the subproject. Note also, that you should **install** SDL2 for make it work, simply *building* is not sufficient. Suggestion: try to **manually install** 3d part libraries and make the project working. Only after that try automatical installation via `ExternalPackage_Add`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see, I can make the project working if I do install the libraries manually, but I just want a cmake file that would install `sdl2` and `sld2-image` without me having to manually install them.

Can you please help me?